# Cordova email composer doesn't work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, email, ionic-framework

I have a big problem with this plugin:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

when i tried to send email on ios, all work well. but when i tried in Android, it did nothing.. And i receive the callback "email view is dismissed". I tested it on some device with different android version and in a blank project. My simple code:

```
cordova.plugins.email.open({app: 'mailto'}, function () {
    console.log('email view dismissed');
}, this);
```

Comment: Check if plugins are properly installed or not.

Comment: yes it's installed.. Because it work on iOS. I found on github that it's a issue with the new version 0.8.3 and the new Cordova 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing this:

cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git#0.8.2

and remove the last version.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out, just wasted hours. This plugin developer needs to read http://semver.org/. Who introduces changes like this in a point release?

Comment: Exact issues. Thanks for posting the solution

Comment: html links are truncated by gmail. Anybody have idea, how to get work with hyperlinks in this plugin?

Comment: hi, this solve the android problem but generate an error into ios. So I need to go back to 0.8.3 to build ios.  How can I make it work together?

Answer (score 1):

add the following code at the indicated address, in new versions of android it requests the action of sending mail

...\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
    <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Shows how here: https://ionicacademy.com/send-emails-with-ionic/

Answer (score -2):

Following the process at this link helped me:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordovaemailcomposer-can-not-send-mail/50395/11

ignore the ionic part.

--EDIT--

You may try with these steps:

1. Remove the plugin and android platform from your project.
2. Add the email plugin from here:https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git
3. Add the Android platform.

I think the trick is you need to add the plugin before adding the android platform. Sounds silly but worked for me.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).