# Seeking advice with setting up email composer in PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, cordova, email, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

Hoping someone can help me troubleshoot my problems getting the email composer plugin to work in my PhoneGap app (with JQueryMobile).

I have the plugin in my config.xml as follows;

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git" >
```

And the below javascript that launches onload.

The 'Ready' alert comes up on the screen - so deviceready is working - but the "email avail" alert after does not come up.

Subsequent javascript to try to launch email does nothing - I suspect that if I can get this first 'cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable' working and the subsequent alert then things will fall into place

Any suggestions as to what I could try to get this working? What could be preventing the cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable from working?

Note: I do have the cordova.js referenced in the html header, and given my apps otherwise build and install correctly I 'believe' it shoudn't be a problem with cordova... should it?

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // cordova.plugins.email is now available 
}, false);

alert("Ready");

cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
    function (isAvailable) {
        //alert('Service is not available') unless isAvailable; 
    }
);

alert("email avail");

cordova.plugins.email.open({
to:      'jobloggs.gmail.com',
subject: 'Feedback'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered in post
[Cordova email composer doesn't work on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128158/cordova-email-composer-doesnt-work-on-android?rq=1)

Mail now launches successfully!